# How many Calories Deficit Equals 1 KG Loss, approximately

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, body-weight

How many Calories Deficit Equals 1 KG Lost?

I intend to loose weight and burn 500 calories daily in Gym. How many Calories Deficit Equals 1 KG Weight Loss, approximately?

Comment: No one has answer to this question?

Comment: Approximately 8000 Kcal. But in practice you'll end up having to eat more to keep up with higher exercise intensity. You can't burn only fats, due to the fact that fat requires a lot more oxygen to burn compared to carbs,so it cannot provide you with high power. Fat is thus low octane fuel, you will burn it together with carbs.Weight loss will happen over time due to your body deciding to keep lower fat reserves, you don't have to do much for that other than exercising a lot and eating healthy foods.

Comment: You should check the supertracker https://www.supertracker.usda.gov/bwp/index.html developed by the NIH is based on this article http://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(11)60812-X/abstract which represents, to date, the best method for estimating weight loss (the author shows this in the article). The model was built using 50 different  studies and has been able to accurately predict the result of additional 18.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Burning 3,500 calories equals 1 pound of weight loss. To lose 1 kilogram of body weight, you would need to create a deficit of about 7,700 calories.

As stated above, 3,500 calories equals about 1 pound (0.45 kilogram) of fat, you need to burn 3,500 calories more than you take in to lose 1 pound.

So, in general, if you cut 500 calories from your typical diet each day, you'd lose about 1 pound a week (500 calories x 7 days = 3,500 calories).

Calories burned during exercise is affected by body weight, intensity of workout, conditioning level and metabolism.

References: 
http://www.livestrong.com/article/370797-how-much-weight-in-kilograms-should-you-aim-to-lose-per-week-while-dieting/

http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/weight-loss/basics/weightloss-basics/hlv-20049483

Comment: I will add more when I am not on mobile, but 3500 cals=1 lb is not really borne out by science. It is more misapplied math from a late 1950's paper than anything. It also varies from person to person.

Comment: Yeah it's just rough estimation which might have just logical explanations...and it sure does vary from person to person

Comment: IIRC, it was related to the energy when burned, which doesn't translate well to body energy.

Comment: Starting October 2014 I embarked on a 500 Kcal deficit per day regimen achieved mostly by boosting exercise (monitored with a FitBit Zip) and slightly reducing intake.  I consistently lost 1 lb per week for the 35 weeks it took to get to my target weight.

Comment: I thought 1 gram of fat is 9 Kcal. So it should follow that 1Kg of fat should be 9,000 Kcal. How come there are 3,500 Kcal only in 1 pound? Thanks